# MySQL error: Using unsupported buffer type: 3 with unsigned integers and mysql_stmt_bind_result()

Tags: mysql, c

If I bind an unsigned integer mysql_stmt_bind_result() returns 1 and id_mysql_stmt_error() gives me:

"Using unsupported buffer type: 3  (parameter: 1)"

Same result with MYSQL_TYPE_LONG, MYSQL_TYPE_TINY, MYSQL_TYPE_SHORT if the param 'is_unsigned' is set to TRUE.

```
// sql string is "SELECT some_ulong FROM some_table WHERE other_num='1'"
// init, prepare, execute return 0, all is fine up to this point
// here I try to bind to some_ulong

result[0].buffer_type   = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
result[0].buffer        = (void *)&longStorage;
result[0].buffer_length = sizeof(long);
result[0].is_unsigned   = 1;  // Works fine if set to 0
result[0].is_null       = &is_null[0];
result[0].length        = NULL;

// Bind result
if (!returnCode)
   returnCode = mysql_stmt_bind_result (sqlStatement, &result[0]);
```

I have the problem on Windows and with Connector 6.0.2. Same code on macOS with Connector 6.0.2. accessing the same server works fine.

Sure, I can ignore that unsigned flag but sending a number that overflows a signed integer produces another kind of error.

Comment: In the end, using snprintf() and strtoul() and sending and receiving unsigned integers as MYSQL_TYPE_STRING was the only thing I could do.